# How do I create header files in C++ projects in Xcode 3.1.2?

Tags: xcode, header-files

I am trying to create a header file in my xcode 3.1.2. Here's what I do.

I start up xcode, I do a new project and save it as Tricycle.

Then they ask me: Choose a template for your new project.
The menu pops up and I go to COMMAND LINE UTILITY to select the "C++ tool".

Once I do the project on the already existing main.cpp, I save it as a main.hpp (I even tried main.h) in the project folder Tricycle (which by the way has the directory on my desktop, I did not change anything as to where it goes to reach the source code).

Now this is how I know I've achieved something by saving it as .hpp: it's because the icon changes from that with a blue coloured C to a maroon coloured H.

I open up a new project, the one I intend to save as a .cpp, called TricycleNew, again --> command line utility --> c++ tool.

In the beginning I code:     #include "main.hpp"

and it says that directory doesn't exist.

Please help me out, I'm new to programming and especially xcode and I want to advance in my learnings but I can't because of this roadblock.

Ant ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are making too many projects. You only need one project, and then you need to add additional files to that project (File -> New File -> Header File).